# Bootstrap 4 compatibility with Font Awesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, icons, font-awesome, twitter-bootstrap-4

Does Bootstrap 4 work well with Font Awesome?

Bootstrap 4 just hit beta, and I'm concerned that Font Awesome is not even listed in [Bootstrap's official "preferred icon set" page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/).

[image: Bootstrap 4 preferred icon sets]

Comment: Font Awesome's framework is completely separate from Bootstrap.  There should be no conflict.

Comment: I understand, but just concerned about why its not even listed among Bootstrap's preferred icon libraries.

Comment: It may be due to their preference for SVG implementation, which is not present in the current iteration of Font Awesome (But is part of FA5).  As far as "Can I use this with that?" though... yes.

Comment: Would you like to add your comment as an answer? I can mark that as the answer and close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font Awesome is completely separate from the Bootstrap Framework and should function within its components without issue.  Bootstrap 4 seems to favor SVG-based icon solutions and that may contribute to why Font Awesome is not on their list of preferred icon solutions.

That being said - Font Awesome 5 is currently in Beta 2 as of 8/15/17.  It has SVG icon support so if that is important to you it may be an option to consider.  I would note though; that Font Awesome 5 is a premium service.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 2.x.x Glyphyicons were in image format, hence you can't increase the size, change the color, background-color, etc easily. However, font-awesome gives you scalable vector icons that can instantly be customized — size, color, drop-shadow, and anything that can be done with the power of CSS.

Font-awesome is really an alternative for Glyphyicons which is getting updated time-to-time with new icons. Fat and Mdo are planning to integrate Font-awesome in bootstrap version 3 as a replacement for Glyphyicons

Answer (score 0):

The following works using font awesome 5's 'web fonts' alternative method instead of svg.
It resizes the icon using css and works with bootstrap's btn class.

```js
$('i').click(function() {
 $(this).removeClass('fa-sort btn-light')
  .addClass('fa-sort-up btn-primary')
})
```

```css
i.fas {
 font-size:200px;
}
```

```html
<i class="btn btn-light fas fa-sort"></i>
```